# Are these PDF object's presence normal in all documents which use Acroforms or XFA forms?

Tags: security, pdf, reverse-engineering, acrobat, exploit

```
2 0 obj
<</XFA 1 0 R >>
endobj

3 0 obj
<<
  /Extensions
  <<
     /ADBE
     <<
        /ExtensionLevel 3
        /BaseVersion /1.7
     >>
   >>
   /AcroForm 2 0 R
   /Type /Catalog
   /Pages 4 0 R
   /NeedsRendering true
>>
endobj
```

Actually, I was analyzing a PDF with CVE-2013-2729 where a specially crafted RLE8 encoded bitmap image causes a integer overflow via the XFA component of Adobe Reader.

Also, what is the difference between an direct and indirect object in PDF ?I am always confused in these two.

Comment: You mention security, RE and exploit but it does not seem relevant to the *question*, does it?

Comment: I have mentioned those since its a vulnerability and I am trying to RE a exploit which has these objects.So basically, what I don't know is ,if object number 3 is normal or has malicious properties.According to me:These are normal but still I wanted to confirm. :-)

Comment: The main culprit in this exploit is a bitmap image which is present in a stream in object number 1 which is encoded twice (\Flatedecode).So,what I want to know is ,is there anything suspicious about these two objects

Comment: Note:I am a noob in RE/VA :-)

Comment: *what I want to know is ,is there anything suspicious about these two objects* - No, they look completely normal and adequate for a pure XFA form PDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, these objects look completely innocent.

Secondly, the difference between direct and indirect objects is exactly what you would expect. If you look at the line:

```
<</XFA 1 0 R >>
```

That's the use of an indirect object. The object is defined elsewhere and in this dictionary it's referred to (indirected).

If you look at the line

```
/ExtensionLevel 3
```

That's the use of a direct object. The object is defined in place without indirection.